# Regular expression inbetween two strings, excluding string

Tags: regex

I am trying to use regex to select the constants from the XML below where the constant is anything COM_CCJET_FORM_ * _NAME 
Except when the constant contains either FIRST_NAME or LAST_NAME

```
<field name="name" type="text" filter="safehtml" class="input-xxlarge input-large-text"
label="COM_CCJET_FORM_LBL_WORKORDER_NAME" description="COM_CCJET_FORM_DESC_WORKORDER_NAME" required="true"
hint="COM_CCJET_FORM_LBL_WORKORDER_NAME" />

<field name="first_name" type="text"
label="COM_CCJET_FORM_LBL_CONTRACTOR_FIRST_NAME" description="COM_CCJET_FORM_DESC_CONTRACTOR_FIRST_NAME"
required="true" menu_published="0" filter="string" directory_stripext="true"
directory_hidenode="true" directory_hidedefault="true"
alias_generator="2135354" heading="h4" close="true" option_on="Yes"
option_off="Yes" />
```

I am able to get anything that has COM_CCJET_FORM_*_NAME with the regex:

```
COM_CCJET_(.*?)_NAME
```

But I can't figure out how to tell the regex to exclude "FIRST"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use negative lookbehinds:

```
COM_CCJET_([^"]*?)(?<!FIRST|LAST)_NAME
```

[*Demo*](https://regex101.com/r/IuWnzz/3)

Comment: Or equivalently, `...(?<!FIRST|LAST)...`

Comment: Nice! I can accept correct answer in 9 min (so SE tells me). Thanks!

Comment: Also, I would suggest something like `\w+` instead of `.*?` - since the latter could get all sorts of weird matches for odd input e.g. `label="COM_CCJET_FOO" ... label="COM_CCJET_FORM_LBL_WORKORDER_NAME"`

Comment: @TomLord I tried it with an additional set of parens first, and regex101 told me that assertions have to be fixed-length. Updating

Comment: It depends on the regex library. Since OP didn't mention which language/tool they're using, I don't know what's supported (including whether or not negative lookbehinds are supported!)

Comment: @TomLord Re: regex lib: I used pcre. It works, just not with additional parens. Re: `\w+`: Changed it to `[^"]`

Comment: When I say "OP", I mean the person who posted the question, not you :)